# Rails - Render/Refresh the current view with new data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

Edit: For easier example, skip to EDIT part. Thanks !

I'm trying to implement a pretty simple thing into my app.

I have a view with a chart, which is based on two query params: :from and :to. I'm using "Chartkick" and these are my view and my controller.

index view (with a debug)

```
<%= params %>

<input type="text" id="from-date">
<%= column_chart dashboard_chart_path(:from => @from, :to => @to)  %>
```

controller

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @from = params[:from]
    @to = params[:to]
  end

  def call_from_ajax
    from = params[:from]
    to = params[:to]
    render action: 'index', to: to, from: from
  end

end
```

Everything works fine. When I type the query params in my URL, the chart displays the correct informations.
Now I have this JS code (for testing):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#from-date').pickadate({
      onClose: function() {
        array ={
          "from": "20-05-2018",
          "to": "01-05-2018"
        }
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'dashboard_chart_ajax',
          data: array
        })
      },
  });
```

route

```
get 'dashboard_chart_ajax', to: 'dashboard#call_from_ajax'
```

The ajax call works perfectly fine. My 'call_from_ajax' method is called and my console displays that the Index view has been rendered. But the params variable in my view do not update, neither the chart ... (I checked with byebug, params contains :from and :to values)
What am I missing ? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

All content above is juste for practice. Let's take another example:

I added a route

```
get 'button', to: "dashboard#test"
```

My controller methods

```
def test
  redirect_to controller: :dashboard, action: :index, from: 'start_date', to: 'end_date'
end

def index
  @from = params[:from]
  @to = params[:to]
end
```

And a button in the view

```
<%= button_to "Some Button", button_path, method: :get, remote: true %>
<%= params %>
```

I want the params variable in the view to update when I click on the button.

When I first load the page, in the :index method I have:

```
 <ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"dashboard", "action"=>"index"} permitted: false>
```

When I click on the button, I have :

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"from"=>"start_date", "to"=>"end_date", "controller"=>"dashboard", "action"=>"index"} permitted: false>
```

But nothing is changing in the view...
It's so frustrating, but I'm learning and must be missing something.

My goal is to change a variable with my 'test' method, and then display it in the same view.

If somebody can help me, it would much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be potentially a couple of problems.

First, you're not *doing* anything with the AJAX response. I would expect something along the lines of:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#from-date').pickadate({
    onClose: function() {
      array ={
        "from": "20-05-2018",
        "to": "01-05-2018"
      }
      ajaxResponse = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'dashboard_chart_ajax',
        data: array
      })
      ajaxResponse.success(data) {
        // do some stuff with the returned data
      }
    },
});
```

My syntax may be off as I've been writing exclusively in coffescript for a while now. Apoloogies in advance.

Second, the `$(document).ready` bit may or may not be a problem depending on whether or not you're using turbolinks. Personally, I remove turbolinks from all of my projects because I don't find it useful. So, that's a bit of a stab in the dark.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think it is an Ajax problem here. I edited my question with an easier example.

Comment: Why do you think anything would change in the view if you're not doing anything with the result of the `$.ajax` call?

Comment: My apologies. My knowledge about Ajax is still pretty low. I took the response of the ajax call, selected the elements that I want, then replaced an element in my DOM. It works perfectly ! I just thought that the Ajax call will tell to Rails to change params and refresh itself the page. But that is not the way it is working apparently. Thanks again !

Comment: Sure thing and glad it works. Perhaps you might upvote/accept.

Answer (score 0):

By adding `remote: true` to the button you tell Rails to perform async request instead of regular page switch. Thus, Ajax call is sent and nothing is done with its response at all. To reflect changes on the page you could do two things: either stick with regular call by removing `remote` attribute or bind a callback to ajax request completion. Second approach is more difficult to implement but more flexible and powerful.

Here is an example of binding callbacks to rails UJS events: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax

Comment: Indeed, it works without the remote:true ! I'm still pretty lost with the asynchronous things ... Thank you !